# why my NSImageView in NSCollectionViewItem'view is nil?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

In IB I create a `NSCollectionView` and its `NSCollectionViewItem` and a `NSView` which belongs to `NSCollectionViewItem`.My `NSCollectionItem` consist of a `NSImageView` and a `NSTextField`.I set them values using cocoa bindings.I want to change the border color of `NSImageView` when `NSCollectionItem` is selected.I create their own classes for all of them and set their custom class in IB.In `NSCollectionViewItem` class I rewrite its  `setSelected:(BOOL)flag` function.The code is

```
 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)flag
{
   [super setSelected:flag];

   [[self view] setSelected:flag];
   [[self view] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

I want to change the border color when the `NSView` calls its draw function.In the `NSView` class I create `IBOutlets` of the `NSImageView` and `NSTextField`,connecting them with IB.But when the draw function is called , I use the code

```
if(selected){
    NSLog(@"self.imageView = %@",self.imageView);
}
```

The result is nil.Why I can't get the imageView of selected NSCollectionViewItem? Where I make the mistake? Help me ,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`NSCollectionViewItem` is the subclass of `NSViewController`.So,in ib,I connect the `NSImageView`  of the `NSView` with the imageView of the `NSCollectionViewItem` and set the NSImageView's class to my own class which is subclass of `NSImageView`.In the draw function of the `NSImageView`,the result of `NSLog` is not nil and I can draw something of myself.